# SignalR is not able to handle the request with respect to the sequence sent from server

Tags: wcf, signalr

In case of triggering multiple signalR events, Is it possible to handle the sequence of these events in client side.

for example:

1:02:01 pm  first event has been triggered           event A

1:02:02 pm  second event has been triggered      event B

1:02:03 pm  third event has been triggered          event C

1:02:04 pm  fourth event has been triggered        event D

Client Side:

I am receiving events in disorder manner (B, D, A, C).

Is it problem with SignalR or handling the outgoing request/response in asp.net?

Answer (score 1):

SignalR guarantees the ordering of messages (which in this case are events), but you need to ensure that your calls do not overlap or become reordered. If events A-D are triggered by web requests invoked in some particular order on the client, there is no guarantee that the server will process those requests in the order they were sent (assuming the client doesn't wait for a response before sending the next request).

The easiest way to ensure that SignalR sends events in the appropriate order is to trigger all your events on the same thread or continuation. If you are using a backplane (e.g. Service Bus, SQL Server, or Redis) as your message bus, you should `await` your calls. Even if you are using the default message bus, awaiting calls doesn't hurt but isn't strictly necessary.

```
public async Task MyHubMethod()
{
   await Clients.All.eventA();
   await Clients.All.eventB();
   await Clients.All.eventC();
   await Clients.All.eventD();
}
```

If you are unable to trigger all of your events in a single hub method, you will probably need to create some sort of queue that then uses [`GetHubContext`](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#callfromoutsidehub) to trigger events.

I should also add that ordering is only guaranteed for messages sent to the same "signal" or destination. In the following code, there is not guaranteed order that `eventA` and `eventB` be invoked in on the caller since one call uses `Clients.All` and the other uses `Clients.Caller`.

```
public async Task MyHubMethod()
{
   await Clients.All.eventA();
   // eventB *might* be invoked before eventA
   await Clients.Caller.eventB();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this information : "ordering is only guaranteed for messages sent to the same signal". Can you specify where this information can be found in the documentation?